# Mysql high Created_tmp_tables

Tags: mysql, performance, performance-tuning

I am seeing some high `Created_tmp_tables` and I just can't seem to figure out where they are coming from. Those rates apparently cause high `Opened_tables` aswell. PhpMyAdmin is complaining that `Opened_tables / Uptime` is too high. Here are some of my status values:

```
+---------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name             | Value  |
+---------------------------+--------+
| Created_tmp_disk_tables   | 4      |
| Created_tmp_files         | 1387   |
| Created_tmp_tables        | 326903 |
| Innodb_num_open_files     | 586    |
| Open_files                | 420    |
| Opened_files              | 420    |
| Uptime                    | 317737 |
| Uptime_since_flush_status | 317737 |
| Opened_table_definitions  | 21817  |
| Opened_tables             | 16651  |
+---------------------------+--------+
```

How can I figure out what's causing this and is there any way to lower it? Or are these values actually fine?

Comment: Neither of those is necessarily "too high".  What matters is if you have slow queries that may (or may not) be affected by the 'high' values.  Start with the [_SlowLog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog)

Comment: Trick is to divide these numbers by the Uptime and see if that's particularly high.

Comment: @RickJames The slow log sometimes logs some queries that are slow for some reason, but only a few but those are really slow then (4 seconds or even more). It's not really an issue but phpMyAdmin did complain about the rate (so value divided by uptime) was "too high" so I wanted to reduce it.

Comment: @danblack Thats what I/phpMyAdmin did and it deemed those as "too high"

Comment: It's not really 'too high' if it does not hurt your website.  As for the slowlog doing 'dumb' things, this may be because of 'dumb' defaults.  My link makes "less-dumb" suggested settings.